# Is it possible to fine-tune a (Spanish RoBERTa) model for a different task?

Tags: bert, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, huggingface

I'm doing sentiment analysis of Spanish tweets.

After reviewing some of the recent literature, I've seen that there's been a most recent effort to train a [RoBERTa model](https://huggingface.co/BSC-TeMU/roberta-large-bne) exclusively on Spanish text. It seems to perform better than the current state-of-the-art model for Spanish language modeling so far, [BETO](https://huggingface.co/dccuchile/bert-base-spanish-wwm-uncased).

The initial BETO model has been trained with the Whole Word Masking technique for a variety of tasks, but **does not include text classification**.

However, I've come across a [model](https://huggingface.co/finiteautomata/beto-sentiment-analysis#beto-sentiment-analysis) that used the BETO model to create a model that is able to do text classification - more precisely, sentiment analysis.

It seems therefore possible to have a baseline model that cannot perform a certain task and fine-tune (or is it train?) for a different task.

**QUESTION:**
Would it, therefore, be possible to take the afore-mentioned RoBERTa model - which in its initial form cannot perform text classification - and fine-tune it to a different task (sentiment analysis in tweets)? 
If so, how would I go about this? Can someone name any helpful resources?

Note: I have a labelled dataset with Spanish Tweets that I could use for fine-tuning.

Comment: Sure, that's precisely the purpose of transfer learning, to be able to use a model pretrained in one task where the data is abundant for another task where it is not. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet. The most obvious resource is [huggingface's tutorial](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would this be possible to do on a local machine or would I need several GPUs?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/83957/14675) helps you with the hardware part.